# Node.js: Server-side Javascript consume more memory

Tags: node.js

I have two Server on nodejs.
First Nodejs Server

```
Runs on Port: 3000.
```

And Another One is on

```
Port: 3001.
```

When I am Starting First Server Then Cpu Usage is As usual i.e Normal.

But when I started My Second Server then it consumes more CPU Usage, memory & Disk.

> Initially, I thought that there is something in my code. After deep
>   debugging I Removed the entire code from server file

Final code of my nodejs server is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));
app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Server Started on Port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

Still, it uses the same amount of memory and CPU usage. If Anyone has some clue regarding this then please let me know.

Any Help is Appreciated...!!

Comment: What is your `node` version?

Comment: Is there something that is regularly making requests on port 3001 and thus keeping that server really busy?  How much CPU and memory is consumed by second server?

Comment: Node Js version is: v6.11.4 LTS

Comment: @jfriend00 then suggest me some other port. I can Tell you the result of using that port.

Comment: You want me to pick a port number?  How about 8001?  I was asking you to do a little debugging on your server and figure out if that might be happening.

Comment: @jfriend00 Now using 8001. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: How much CPU and memory is consumed by second server?

Comment: Second server : 3001 or 8001 usage: 37%. while Primary Server: 3000 usage 0%

Comment: Can you please provide a full piece of source code that reproduces the problem (as stack overflow would call a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example".  We can only make wild guesses without being able to reproduce the problem ourselves.  And, then if that code only reproduces the problem on your system and not ours, we will know that it has something to do with your system or your node.js version or your node.js installation.  If it reproduces on our system, then we can debug it.

Comment: Are you sure that `process.env.PORT` is not set?

Comment: Its Solve. Actually It is due to using nodemon. when I started My server with "node app.js" then its usage is 0% and when i started with "nodemon" then its usage becomes 30%